# How do I detect when an item is on top of a specific block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been all around Google trying to find this out. I am making a data pack with a custom crafter and I have the summon command all ready. I want to be able to throw a diamond block on top of a blast furnace and turn it into the crafter.

Comment: Can you post the commands you already have and what you have tried to get this done? Questions like this tend to fall on deaf ears if you don't provide evidence you actually tried to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The command:**

Run this command every tick (or every second to save on lag)

```
execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond_block",Count:1b}}] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:blast_furnace run function namespace:summon_crafter
```

---

**How it works:**

`execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond_block",Count:1b}}]`
Runs the rest of the command as all item entities that are a single diamond block.

`at @s` Runs the command at the location of any detected diamond blocks

`if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:blast_furnace` Check if the block underneath it is a blast furnace

`run function namespace:summon_crafter` Summon your crafter

Comment: Absolute legend!